# Uploading WSO2 Integration Studio 8.0.0 API Project in API Publisher Portal ( API Manager 3.1.0)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I would like someone to answer my question:
how a project created in Integration Studio 8.0.0 can be imported into the **API Publisher Portal** of the **API Manager 3.1.0** .
I have performed the steps specified on the official WSO2 page : **https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/creating-and-uploading-using-integration-studio/** but at the end of step 13. and check if the sequence has been uploaded correctly to https://localhost:9443/carbon( API Manager) in my case is not uploaded correctly. I have to do it using **API Controller apictl 3.1.5** to perform the upload of the APIs developed with Integration Studio 8.0 by copying the xml sequence of the Integration by pasting it into a notepad and saving it to the folder of the project to be imported under this folder directory : Sequences--> in-sequence-> fileSquence.xml. Once this is done, using command lines : *apictl import-api --file C: Users Documents workspace Project-1.0.0 --environment local -k* I get to publish the API in the API Publisher Portal. Is there an easier and more viable way ?
This resembles Mulesoft, only in this tool , from the Anypoint Studio we export a . jar of our project and with this . jar we head to the Anypoint Platform and select "Upload file jar" to upload our project. Thank you!

I have not been able to upload the API created from Integration Studio 8.0.0 to the API Publisher Portal of API Manager 3.1.0. Is there a choice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the API via the publisher portal and the above-shared link shows how you can add mediation sequences to the publisher portal and how you can use it in the API request or response path. You can do it by just adding sequence files via the publisher's portal. Please refer [1].

[1]  https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/#creating-per-api-mediation-policies